# How to set page variable from custom module

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 8:

I have custom module code that declares its own theme can twig template.  How do I make module variables available to my Drupal theme's page.html.twig?

I have tried various preprocess_page* functions; however, those functions don't see the variables the module is passing to it's own themed twig templates.

Can the module's controller inject something into the page variables?

Can a Drupal theme's preprocess functions access some variables flowing from a custom module to the module's twig templates?

The controller file:

```
class PromtController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function program($id)
    {
        $program = PromtService::program((int)$id);

        return [
            '#theme'   => 'promt_program',
            '#program' => $program,
            '#title'   => $program['title']
        ];
    }
}
```

The module code:

```
function promt_theme()
{
    return [
        'promt_program' => [
            'template' => 'promt_program',
            'variables' => [
                'program' => null
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Normally, the hook_preprocess_page() implementation would appear in your .module file, the same file where you implemented hook_theme().

Comment: The hook_preprocess_page() function; however, does not seem to have access to the programs variable being passed from the controller to the theme.

I need to inspect the programs variable I'm passing in, in order to pull out phone numbers, etc to add as contact information in page.html.twig.  Either hook_preprocess_page() needs to be able to find that variable some where in &$vars[] or the controller needs to pass it in, in a special way, such that it becomes part of the page array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this should be handled in the custom theme, not in the custom module.  This is because the module really has no idea how a custom theme wants to render stuff.

In any case, in the custom theme, the only way I can figure out how to make the data available is to register a hook_preprocess() function in the theme, check the hook that's called, and declare a static variable that sticks around until it can be injected later on.

The custom module's "promt_program" hook will be called earlier than the theme's "page" hook. I'm pretty sure that will always be true.  So, we grab the location_id and then inject it later on.

This preprocess function will get called many, many times, so it seems important to make it thin.

```
function cob_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
    static $location_id = null;

    switch ($hook) {
        case 'promt_program':
            if (!empty($vars['program']['location_id'])) { $location_id = $vars['program']['location_id']; }
        break;

        case 'page':
            if ($location_id) {
                $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                    ->condition('status', 1)
                    ->condition('type', 'location')
                    ->condition('field_promt_id', $location_id);
                $nids  = $query->execute();
                if ($nids) {
                    $vars['node'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load(current($nids));
                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
```